# How to run distinct and Sum in one query in sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sum, distinct, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have a table #1 as shown in image attached. First i want to sum all quantity of all distinct id. Then want to show number of id that have same quantity.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain to me the relation of total Id and the second table? I'm having trouble understanding

Comment: @NemanjaT there is no relation. Actually there is just 1 table exists.

Comment: Look at Felix's answer, the query I came up with is nearly identical as his.

Comment: @NemanjaT there is problem in his query. It's only returning direct from table 1. While i want to add qty first for id let us say 1 from table 1. then again want to check how many id's have qty sum as id 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one after creating a temporary table

```
create table #Temp
(
  id int, 
  qty int
)

Insert Into #Temp
SELECT  id, SUM(qty)
        FROM yourTable
        group by id

SELECT  * FROM #Temp

SELECT  Count(id) , qty
        FROM #Temp
        GROUP BY qty
        ORDER BY qty DESC
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `SUM` and `COUNT`:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS totalId,
    qty
FROM (
    SELECT
        id, SUM(qty) AS qty
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY id
)t
GROUP BY qty
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/489844)</kbd>

Comment: It's returning just one record that is '1289002, 1'

Comment: the query is good though, so it has to be something else that's troubling you.

Comment: there is problem in his query. It's only returning direct from table 1. While i want to add qty first for id let us say 1 from table 1. then again want to check how many id's have qty sum as id 1

Comment: His query is good, just make a temp table and insert results of first query into it, after that do outer select  .... or just make 2 queries, first with inner select and 2nd one as both inner and outer select

Comment: @JaniMani: This query perfectly solves the problem you stated.

Comment: @Veljko89 can you make it for me please

Comment: @dnoeth, no it's not what i am looking for

Comment: @JaniMani Write it for you? This website is for solving already existing code... not a code give-away website...

Comment: How you gonna learn if someone else would write it for you? google SQL temp table, write it down and learn something new ... you have all you need right in front of you, give it a shot, if you fail, come back, show us what you have done and we will help you after you have tried it yourself first

Comment: @Jani Mani: We all agree here that this answers your question perfectly. As you can see from the linked demo, the query returns exactly the result you are looking for. So you should accept this answer. If you have an addtional request, create a new separate question.

Comment: Thanks everyone for covering for me. @JaniMani, does this solve your problem?

Comment: @FelixPamittan Yes Man... Thanks U Specially :)

Answer (score 0):

to show the sum of all quantities of all distinct id:

```
SELECT id,SUM(qty) FROM table GROUP BY id;
```

to show number of id that have same quantity

```
SELECT count(id),quantity FROM (SELECT id,SUM(qty) AS quantity FROM table GROUP BY id) GROUP BY quantity
```

Comment: Well, this is the same answer @FelixPamittan wrote 15 minutes earlier :)

Comment: @dnoeth, It's not like that. I want to SUM in TABLE 1 and want to get result like Table 2. Then from Table 2 i want to get result like Required Table